# SVM prediction of data in cells rather than the expected matrix

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, libsvm, vlfeat

For my svm training and prediction I am using `vl_svmtrain`, the documentation of which can be found here: http://www.vlfeat.org/matlab/vl_svmtrain.html

> [W B] = VL_SVMTRAIN(X, Y, LAMBDA) trains a linear Support Vector
>   Machine (SVM) from the data vectors X and the labels Y. X is a D by N
>   matrix, with one column per example and D feature dimensions (SINGLE
>   or DOUBLE). Y is a DOUBLE vector with N elements with a binary (-1 or
>   +1) label for each training point.

According to the documentation the data `X` must be in a D by N matrix having one sample per column.

The thing is my data is not arranged in this way at all and I don't think I can arrange it like this even if I wanted. Each of my image is represented by a feature matrix of size `512 * 257`, these are stored in a cell. Similarly each test image is also of the same size.

So for the sake of simplification I assume that I only have 3 classes, each class is represented by a model of size `512 * 257` and I have thousands of tests that I must compare agains each model, more like a one vs all approach. But its the data arrangement that I am having difficulty with.

Is it possible to present the data to SVM in cell format rather than the matrix format?

**Update:**

The cell array I mentioned consists of 28 models. So I have a total of 28 classes, each class is represented by a array of size `512 * 257`. Writing `models(1)` presents `ans =  [512x257 double]` and writing `models{1}` produces the `512*257` double matrix.

This is what I am using to train the SVM, similarly each test is also of the same size, and in the same arrangement.

How I got this matrix for each model? I extracted the RootSIFT features from 100 images for each class/model. I then presented these features to a gaussian mixture model script and set the number of clusters to be 512. This gave me the means, covariances and weights of the 512 clusters. I then concatenated them using `models{i} = [gmm_models{i}.w(:) gmm_models{i}.mu' gmm_models{i}.sigma'];`

As for the test, RootSIFT features are extracted from 5 images, and then they undergo the same process as with the models to get the concatenated matrix of the same size. So naturally for each model there are hundreds of test matrices.

I hope this has clarified it more than before.

Comment: Is the 512x257 by any chance a list of feature points in the image?  With their full descriptors?

Comment: It is a concatenation of the parameters generated by GMM. So each cell is a concatenation of the means, covariances and the weights. These features have been known to produce good results according to a paper published in March last year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to represent the data to the `vl_svmtrain` method other than the `D x N` matrix that it's talking about.  However, what you can do is unroll the cell array and transform each feature matrix so that it becomes **a column vector**.  You would then construct your matrix such that each column vector represents a single feature matrix and concatenate these column vectors width-wise to produce your final `D x N` matrix.

As such, you can do a bit of pre-processing to get your desired matrix `X`.  First, unroll your cell array so that it becomes a 3D matrix where each slice is one feature matrix.  Then, reshape this matrix so that each slice becomes a single column for a final 2D matrix.  Therefore, do something like this, assuming that your cell array is stored in `A`:

```
X_3D = cat(3, A{:});
X = reshape(X_3D, size(X_3D,1)*size(X_3D,2), []);
```

`X` will contain that final 2D matrix we talked about.  Bear in mind that each feature matrix will get unrolled on a **column** basis.  This means that for each feature matrix you have, the columns are stacked on top of each other to create a single column for the output 2D matrix.  You can now use `X` as input into `vl_svmtrain`.

However, I will give you fair warning in that each column would technically be `512 x 257 = 131584` elements.  If you have 1000s of feature matrices, this matrix may be infeasible for use into `vl_svmtrain` due to memory requirements.  Therefore, you may have to either subsample your feature matrix, or use a decreased number of feature matrices for the input.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. That is unfortunate will changing the svm help? Will it work better with libsvm?

Comment: I don't think changing which SVM you're using will help.  The problem is still how much memory your training data is taking up so switching to `libsvm` will probably not do anything.  It has been quite a while since I have used `VLFeat` so before we do anything else, try running `vl_svmtrain` with that reshaped data matrix as is, and see what you get.

Comment: @rayreng The first command produced an error of ``cell contents reference from a non cell array object``, so I changed it to ``X_3D = cat(3, A(:));``. But this and the other command produce the same result, both produce the same thing that ``A(:)`` would produce a vector of size ``131584 * 1``. I do not get a 2D or 3D matrix. Thanks

Comment: @FarazKhan - You told me that `A` was a cell array.  Can you please be more specific on what your input is supposed to be?  Also, if you only get a single column vector, that means that your cell array / whatever it is... is only a **single** feature matrix.  Please update your post with all of your relevant code so I can see what you're doing.

Comment: I am sorry I should have been more clear. I have added more details on the structure of my input. I did not add the code because it was more GMM related than SVM and it would require a lot of commenting to explain my steps. If you want I would gladly add all of the code here as well to show how I got this data.

Comment: @FarazKhan - OK.  If each cell is a `512 x 257` matrix, then the code that I wrote above should work.  Simply replace `A` with `models`.  Can you show me how exactly you are calling the code I wrote above with your `models` cell array?

Comment: My apologies, I believe the mistake was from my end,I used your code like this ``X_3D = cat(3, models{1}(:));`` because I thought I would have to do this individually for each model, now I used it as is and it actually created 28 columns, one for each model so its just perfect. thank you. I believe I should reshape my tests in the same manner as well?

Comment: @FarazKhan - Yes, that's what it's supposed to do... create 28 columns!  One thing you must know with how I post code is that it will always work tailored towards your situation :)  Yes.  You need to do this for your test data as well.  Let me know if this works out for you, and if it does, please consider accepting my answer!